# How to recognize Feynman diagrams from the $S$-matrix expansion?

Tags: operators, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

I'm studying scattering processes in QED and one usually have to compute first of all the Scattering matrix
$$\hat{S}=T\biggl (\exp\{-i\int d^{4}x:\bar{\psi}(x)\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}(x)\hat{\psi}(x):\}\biggr)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\hat{S}^{(n)}.$$
One could show that the first order term of the expansion is useless since each term is kinematically not allowed, however the second-order is the physical relevant one and is given by (exploiting the Wick Theorem)

$$\hat{S}^{(2)}=\frac{(-ie)^{2}}{2!}∫ d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}T\biggl(:\hat{\bar{\psi}}(x_{1})\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}(x_{1})\hat{\psi}(x_{1})::\hat{\bar{\psi}}(x_{2})\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}(x_{2})\hat{\psi}(x_{2}):\biggr)=$$

$$=\frac{(-ie)^{2}}{2!}∫ d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}:\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{1}\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{1}\hat{\psi}_{1}\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{2}\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{2}\hat{\psi}_{2}:(a)$$

$$+\frac{(-ie)^{2}}{2!}∫ d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}<0|T\biggl(\hat{\psi}_{1}\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{2}\biggr)|0>:\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{1}\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{1}\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{2}\hat{\psi}_{2}:(b)$$

$$+\frac{(-ie)^{2}}{2!}∫ d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}<0|T\biggl(\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{1}\hat{\psi}_{2}\biggr)|0>:\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{1}\hat{\psi}_{1}\hat{\bar{\psi}}_{2}\gamma_{\mu}\hat{A}^{\mu}_{2}:(c)$$

$$+other\hspace{0.5cm}contractions$$

and in my notes there's written that those two terms (b),(c) are responsible for the following processes:

[image]

How can I see clearly this fact? Is it correct to split $\hat{\psi}=\hat{\psi}^{(+)}+\hat{\psi}^{(-)}$ as well as $\hat{A}_{\mu}=\hat{A}_{\mu}^{(+)}+\hat{A}_{\mu}^{(-)}$ and expand their product inside the normal ordering? I was thinking that using the normal ordering with the correct signs may cancel some terms and we are left exactly with those processes represented above. Does it make sense?